# HTML: Why might an input with type=hidden appear after </HTML> on a web page?

Tags: html

I just had  a look at html of my twitter page as part of learning HTML. At the end of the page I can see a lot of state as the value of a hidden input tag (the value appears to be in json form).

I see no obvious form associated with this, and it doesn't appear in the html request.

I wonder if anyone might be able to guess how/why these inputs and their values might be used.

```
          </body>
</html>
<input type="hidden" id="init-data" class="json-data" value=" 
{&quot;scribeMetrics&quot;:0,&quot;environment&quot;:&quot;production&quot;,&quot;wtfOptions&quot;:
{&quot;dismissable&quot;:true,&quot;connections&quot;:true,&quot;pc&quot;:true,&quot;limit&quot;:3,&quot;
disabled&quot;:false,&quot;display_location&quot;:&quot;wtf-component&quot;}
```

........ and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at this [javascript file](https://si0.twimg.com/c/swift/init.103c61dd76c3ed5ba2dcffcd63e25fbf4b1442ac.js), you see that the `init-data` element is used

```
var a=$("#init-data").val(),
    b=JSON.parse(a),
    c=$.makeArray(arguments);
b.moreCSSBundle?using("css!"+b.moreCSSBundle,d):d()}if($("html").hasClass("debug"))
//and so on
```

If you want to know, why they used a hidden field and not standard javascript variables, you have to ask the guys responsible for this at twitter themselves ;). I see no obvious reason and the minified code doesn't make it easier to understand what's going on.